# Unable to send Payor name in SecurePay

Tags: php, payment-gateway

```
<?php
$sp->Cc = 4444333322221111;
$sp->ExpiryDate = '10/15';
$sp->ChargeAmount = 1300.08;
$sp->ChargeCurrency = 'USD';
$sp->Cvv = 321;
$sp->OrderId = 'ORD10002';

if ($sp->Valid()) { // Is the above data valid?

$response = $sp->Process();

if ($response == SECUREPAY_STATUS_APPROVED) {
    echo "Transaction was a success\n".'<br>';
    echo $sp->TransactionId.'<br>';

} else {
    echo "Transaction failed with the error code: $response\n";
    echo "XML Dump: ". print_r($sp->ResponseXml,1) . "\n";
}
} else {
die("Your data is invalid\n");
}
?>
```

Here is my code for direct payment from my website(Avoiding redirect to secure payment page).But problem is that I need to pass **payor**(card holder name)from here .That I want to show payor name on my secure payment admin panel,because Payor is going blank.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation...

http://www.securepay.com.au/uploads/Integration%20Guides/Direct_Post_Integration_Guide.pdf

in section 3.4.3 FraudGuard. It looks to have the values you are looking for. Also below in section 3.4.4.1 Payor there are details in sending an ID to store against the details.